# Convert SAS numeric to python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, format

This is probably a simple solution, but how would I go about converting a SAS datetime number (number of seconds since 1/1/1960.)  An example of one of the values inside of the pandas column is 1716470000.

I tried:

```
df['PyDatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df,infer_datetime_format=True)
```

and I get numbers like '1970-01-01 00:00:01.725480'

Comment: Unsolicited advice: it really helps answerers if you provide the desired output. In other words, we know that dates around 1970 are probably wrong, but we still don't know what you're expecting to get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need the built-in `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
sastime = 1716470000
epoch = datetime.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
print(epoch + datetime.timedelta(seconds=sastime))
```

Which shows:

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 23, 13, 13, 20) # is this right?
```

So if you have a dataframe with a column called `sastime`, you could do:

```
epoch = datetime.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
# cast -s- to python int in case it's a string or a numpy.int
df['datetime'] = df['sastime'].apply(
    lambda s: epoch + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(s))
)
```

Comment: PERFECT!!  Thanks so much this will be really handy.

Comment: @Chris note: depending on dtype of the source data, you might need to force `s` to a plain ol' `int`. I'll revise the answer accordingly.