# convert a SAS datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, sas

I am using **Pandas** to read a **Sas** dataset using `read_sas`

There is a datetime variable in the SAS dataset, which appears in Pandas as:

`1.775376e+09`

Once I convert it to `str` the date is:

`1775376002.0`

The corresponding date in SAS (not in my Pandas dataset) appears to be a `DATETIME21.2`

`04APR2016:08:00:02.00`

I tried to convert it using

`pd.to_datetime(df.mysasdate,format='%d%m%Y%H%M%S')` with no success

```
TypeError: 'float' object is unsliceable
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Check out this question. The module datetime has the converter you need, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26923644/4633893

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> SAS date value
>
> is a value that represents the number of days between January 1, 1960, and a specified date. [link](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm)

So you can convert number [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add `date` `1960-01-01 00:00:00`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mysasdate':[1775376002.0, 1775377002.0]})
print (df)
      mysasdate
0  1.775376e+09
1  1.775377e+09

print (pd.to_timedelta(df['mysasdate'], unit='s') + pd.datetime(1960, 1, 1)) 
0   2016-04-04 08:00:02
1   2016-04-04 08:16:42
Name: mysasdate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: actually I get `ValueError: time data '1775376002.0' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)`

Comment: I think you used the format of what the date appears to be like in SAS

Answer (score 2):

You will get the right date in Python by using format='sas7bdat' option in your read_sas() method. For example, I used: pd.read_sas(dataset, format='sas7bdat'), and the dates got translated correctly to python dataframe.