# convert a SAS datetime in Pandas - Multiple Columns

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to learn Python, coming from a SAS background.
I have imported a SAS dataset, and one thing I noticed was that I have multiple date columns that are coming through as SAS dates (I believe).
In looking around, I found a link which explained how to perform this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500348/convert-a-sas-datetime-in-pandas)):

The code is as follows:

```
alldata['DateFirstOnsite'] = pd.to_timedelta(alldata.DateFirstOnsite, unit='s') + pd.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
```

However, I'm wondering how to do this for multiple columns.  If I have multiple date fields, rather than repeating this line of code multiple times, can I create a list of fields I have, and then run this code on that list of fields?  How is that done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create a list and iterate through that list to convert the SAS date fields to pandas datetime. However, I'm not sure why you're using a `to_timedelta` method, unless the SAS date fields are represented by seconds after 1960/01/01. If you plan on using the `to_timedelta` method, then its simply a case of creating a function that takes your `df` and your field and passing those two into your function:

```
def convert_SAS_to_datetime(df, field):
    df[field] = pd.to_timedelta(df[field], unit='s') + pd.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
    return df
```

Now, let's suppose you have your list of fields that you know should be converted to a datetime field (along with your df):

```
my_list = ['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5']
my_df = pd.read_sas('mySASfile.sas7bdat')  # your SAS data that's converted to a pandas DF
```

You can now iterate through your list with a `for` loop while passing those fields and your df to the function:

```
for field in my_list:
    my_df = convert_SAS_to_datetime(my_df, field)
```

Now, the other method I would recommend is using the [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method, but this assumes that you know what the SAS format of your date fields are.

e.g.  `01Jan2016  # date9 format`

This is when you might have to look through the documentation [here](http://strftime.org/) to determine the directive to converting the date. In the case of a `date9` format, then you can use:

```
df[field] = pd.to_datetime(df[date9field], format="%d%b%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

If i read your question correctly, you want to apply your code to multiple columns? to do that simple do this:

`alldata[['col1','col2','col3']] = 'your_code_here'`

Exmaple:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['Pharmacy of IDAHO','Access medicare arkansas','NJ Pharmacy','Idaho Rx','CA Herbals','Florida Pharma','AK RX','Ohio Drugs','PA Rx','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})

df[['E', 'D']] = 1 # <---- notice double brackets
print(df)

     A    B                         C  D  E
0  NaN  1.0         Pharmacy of IDAHO  1  1
1  NaN  0.0  Access medicare arkansas  1  1
2  3.0  3.0               NJ Pharmacy  1  1
3  4.0  5.0                  Idaho Rx  1  1
4  5.0  0.0                CA Herbals  1  1
5  5.0  0.0            Florida Pharma  1  1
6  3.0  NaN                     AK RX  1  1
7  1.0  9.0                Ohio Drugs  1  1
8  5.0  0.0                     PA Rx  1  1
9  NaN  0.0                USA Pharma  1  1
```

Notice the double brackets in the beginning. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks MattR.  Not quite what I was looking for, but the response below worked great.  Thanks for taking the time to help out.